# parseFeed error in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I try to read two rss feed and i have an error.

This is my ctrl and the factory :

```
app.factory('FeedService', ['$http', function($http){
    return {
        parseFeed : function(url) {
            return $http.jsonp('https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&num=50&callback=JSON_CALLBACK&q=' + encodeURIComponent(url));
        }
    }
}]);

app.controller('ActuCtrl', ['$scope', '$rootScope', 'FeedService', function($scope, $rootScope, Feed1, Feed2) {

        Feed1.parseFeed("https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?id=618857251494402&format=rss20").then(function(res){
            $scope.feeds1=res.data.responseData.feed.entries;
        $scope.quantity1 = 5;
        });

        Feed2.parseFeed("https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?id=149375131740957&format=rss20").then(function(res){
            $scope.feeds2=res.data.responseData.feed.entries;
        $scope.quantity2 = 5;
        });

}]);
```

my html :

```
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="feed in feeds1 | filter:cleanit | limitTo:quantity1">                    
            <p><a href="{{feed.link}}">{{feed.title}}</a></p>                                        
        </li>
    </ul>

    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="feed2 in feeds2 | filter:cleanit | limitTo:quantity2">                    
            <p><a href="{{feed.link}}">{{feed.title}}</a></p>                                        
        </li>
    </ul>
```

and the error:

TypeError: Cannot read property 'parseFeed' of undefined
    at new  (ActuCtrl.js:16:14)

What's wrong ?

Comment: What is `Feed2`? It will be undefined anyways you are not specifying the dependency for that

Comment: For that matter, what is Feed1?

Comment: @MikeRobinson `feed1` will be `FeedService` instance, see the dependencies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
app.controller('ActuCtrl', ['$scope', '$rootScope', 'FeedService', function($scope, $rootScope, Feed) {

    Feed.parseFeed("https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?id=618857251494402&format=rss20").then(function(res) {
        $scope.feeds1 = res.data.responseData.feed.entries;
        $scope.quantity1 = 5;
    });

    Feed.parseFeed("https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?id=149375131740957&format=rss20").then(function(res) {
        $scope.feeds2 = res.data.responseData.feed.entries;
        $scope.quantity2 = 5;
    });

}]);
```

Remove Feed2.